# toggle function making all other divs disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

So I have many divs (planets). I'd like to make them disappear by clicking on them. So far I have earth and sun only. On my test run, when I click on sun, and earth also disappears. What is the proper code so that not all planets will disappear just by one click.

HTML:

```
<div class="planets" id="sun"><div>
<div class-"planets" id="earth"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#sun {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 100% 45%, 0% 97%, from(#FEA901),     to(#FE4801));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FEA901, #FE4801); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FEA901, #FE4801);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FEA901, #FE4801);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #FEA901, #FE4801);
    position:relative;
    border:3px solid orange;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%; 
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -150px;
    border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 5px rgba(255, 255, 190, .75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 5px rgba(255, 255, 190, .75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 250px 100px rgba(240, 176, 12, .75);
}

#earth {
    position:absolute;
    top:440px;
    right:700px;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:1px solid white;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 100% 45%, 0% 97%, from(#068143), t(#FE4801));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2215DF, #068143); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FEA901, #068143);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FEA901, #068143);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #FEA901, #068143);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 5px rgba(131, 180, 226, .75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 5px rgba(131, 180, 226, .75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 10px rgba(131, 180, 226, .75);
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("html").mousemove(function(e){
        $('.follow').css({'top': e.clientY - 100, 'left': e.clientX - 60});
    }); 
    $('.planets').click(function() {
        $('#sun').toggle(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be <div class="planets" id="earth"></div> ?

Comment: that's what i have. i believe?

Comment: Unless you mistyped it in the code box, your current div for earth shows a "-" instead of a "="

Comment: maybe it should be <div class="planets>
                   <div id="earth"></div>
                   <div id="jupiter></div>
                   <div id="saturn></div>?
                   </div>

Comment: i fixed the - = typo. but still the same outcome

Comment: you also had a </div> missing for your sun, which made the html not parse correctly. I fixed your problems and changed it so that each planet disappears by clicking on them on an answer below.

Comment: thanks it was indeed that little /div typo at the end. Thank you! i have to have more attention to detail i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had several typos in your code. You forgot the `</div>` to the sun, which made it not parse correctly and the earth wouldn't show up. Also you had - instead of = for the class. Here is the code for you fixed:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x9zEC/)

Comment: thank you. i had the code right all along. just that little typo. That's my problem in coding. i need to be better in attention to detail!

Comment: @Lo_MAT how is this not the correct answer, considering this one actually has a fiddle that has the code working properly?

Comment: sorry, i meant to check this. pardon me, i'm new to stack overflow so i have to get used to the proper ways

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.planets').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
}
```

you could also do

```
$('.planets').click(function() {
    $(this).toggle();
}
```

but it'd be pointless since you can't click on it to make it reappear, after it is already hidden

Comment: change this <div class-"planets" id="earth"></div> to <div class="planets" id="earth"></div>   you have - instead of =

Comment: basically, if it's possible I just want the divs to disappear not all with a single click but by clicking each div (planets). I don't intend them to reappear.

Comment: @Lo_MAT Ok, so do the first 3 lines of my answer. The one with .hide()

Comment: still the same sorry. Care to fiddle it?